# mxnet: how to set up a custom mx.io.DataIter to prefetch?

Tags: python, iterator, gpu, mxnet, prefetch

My mxnet script is likely limited by i/o of data loading into the GPU, and I am trying to speed this up by prefetching. The trouble is I can't figure out how to prefetch with a custom data iterator.

**My first hypothesis/hope was that it would be enough to set the values of self.preprocess_threads and self.prefetch_buffer**, as I had seen [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/io/io.html) for iterators such as `mxnet.io.ImageRecordUInt8Iter`. However, when I did this I saw no performance change relative to the script before I had set these variables, so clearly setting these did not work.

**Then I noticed, the existence of a class `mx.io.PrefetchingIter`** in addition to the base class for which I had implemented a child class `mx.io.DataIter`. I found this [documentation](http://beta.mxnet.io/api/gluon-related/_autogen/mxnet.io.PrefetchingIter.html), but I have not been able to find any examples, and I am a little confused about what needs to happen where/when. However, I am not clear on how to use this. For example. I see that in addition to `next()` it has an `iter_next()` method, which simply says "move to the next batch". What does this mean exactly? What does it mean to "move" to the next batch without producing it? I found the [source code](http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/1.0.0/_modules/mxnet/io.html) for this class, and based on a brief reading, it seems as though it takes multiple iterators and creates one thread per iterator. This likely would not work for my current design, as I really want multiple threads used to prefetch from the same iterator.

Here is what I am trying to do via a custom data iterator

1. I maintain a global `multiprocessing.Queue` on which I pop data as it becomes available
2. I produce that data by running (via `multiprocessing`) a command line script that executes a c++ binary which produces a `numpy` file
3. I open the `numpy` file and load its contents into memory, process them, and put the processed bits on the global `multiprocessing.Queue`
4. My custom iterator pulls off this queue and also kicks off more jobs to produce more data when the queue is empty.

Here is my code:

```
def launchJobForDate(date_str):
### this is a function that gets called via multiprocessing
### to produce new data by calling a c++ binary
### whenever data queue is empty so that we need to produce more data
    try:
        f = "testdata/data%s.npy"%date_str
        if not os.path.isfile(f):
            cmd = CMD % ( date_str, JSON_FILE, date_str, date_str, date_str)
            while True:
                try:
                    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
                    break
                except:
                    pass
        while True:
            try:
                d = np.load(f)
                break
            except:
                pass
        data_queue.put((d, date_str))
    except Exception as ex:
        print("launchJobForDate: ERROR ", ex)

class ProduceDataIter(mx.io.DataIter):
    @staticmethod
    def processData(d, time_steps, num_inputs):
       try: 
            ...processes data...
            return [z for z in zip(bigX, bigY, bigEvalY, dates)]
        except Exception as ex:
            print("processData: ERROR ", ex)

    def __init__(self, num_mgrs, end_date_str):
        ## iter stuff
        self.preprocess_threads = 4
        self.prefetch_buffer = 1

        ## set up internal data to preserve state
        ## and make a list of dates for which to run binary

    @property
    def provide_data(self):
        return [mx.io.DataDesc(name='seq_var', 
                               shape=(args_batch_size * GPU_COUNT, 
                                      self.time_steps, 
                                      self.num_inputs), 
                               layout='NTC')]

    @property
    def provide_label(self):
        return [mx.io.DataDesc(name='bd_return', 
                                shape=(args_batch_size * GPU_COUNT)),             
                mx.io.DataDesc(name='bd_return', 
                                shape=(args_batch_size * GPU_COUNT, num_y_cols)), 
                mx.io.DataDesc(name='date', 
                               shape=(args_batch_size * GPU_COUNT))]                 


    def __next__(self):
        try:
            z = self.z.pop(0)       
            data = z[0:1]
            label = z[1:]
            return mx.io.DataBatch(data, label) 
        except Exception as ex:
            ### if self.z (a list) has no elements to pop we need
            ### to get more data off the queue, process it, and put it
            ### on self.x so it's ready for calls to __next__()
            while True:
                try:
                    d = data_queue.get_nowait()
                    processedData = ProduceDataIter.processData(d, 
                                                            self.time_steps, 
                                                            self.num_inputs)
                    self.z.extend(processedData)
                    counter_queue.put(counter_queue.get() - 1)

                    z = self.z.pop(0)
                    data = z[0:1]
                    label = z[1:]
                    return mx.io.DataBatch(data, label)

                except queue.Empty:
                    ...this is where new jobs to produce new data and put them 
                    ...on the queue would happen if nothing is left on the queue
```

I have then tried making one of these iterators as well as a prefetch iterator like so:

```
mgr      = ProcessMgr(2, end_date_str)
mgrOuter = mx.io.PrefetchingIter([mgr])
```

The problem is that `mgrOuter` immediately throws a `StopIteration` as soon as `__next__()` is called the first time, and without invoking `mgr.__next__()` as I thought it might.

Finally, I also noticed that `gluon` has a `DataLoader` object which [seems like it might handle prefetching](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/data.html?highlight=dataset#mxnet.gluon.data.Dataset), however in this case it also seems to assume that the underlying data is from a `Dataset` which has a finite and unchanging layout (based on the fact that it is implemented in terms of `getitem`, which takes an index). So I have not pursued this option as it seem unpromising given the dynamic queue-like nature of the data I am generating as training input.

My questions are:

- **How do I need to modify my code above so that there will be prefetching for my custom iterator?**
- **Where might I find an example or more detailed documentation of how mx.io.PrefetchingIter works?**
- Are there other strategies I should be aware of for getting more performance out of my GPUs via a custom iterator? Right now they are only operating at around 50% capacity, and upping (or lowering) the batch size doesn't change this. What other knobs might I be able to turn to increase GPU use efficiency?

Thanks for any feedback and advice.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, gluon DataLoader is providing prefetching. In your custom DataIterator, you are using Numpy arrays as input. So you could do the following:

```
f = "testdata/data%s.npy"%date_str
data = np.load(f)
train = gluon.data.ArrayDataset(mx.nd.array(data))
train_iter = gluon.data.DataLoader(train, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, batch_size=batch_size, last_batch='rollover')
```

Since you are creating your data dynamically, you could try resetting the DataLoader in every epoch and load a new Numpy array. 
If GPU utilization is still low, then try to increase the batch_size and the num_workers. Another problem could be also the size of your dataset. Resetting the DataLoader will impact the performance, so having a larger dataset will increase the time of an epoch and as such increase performance.